# Underscores Problem in Name Mangling from docs Private Variables

Tags: python, class, name-mangling

[Docs->9.Classes->9.6 Private Variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables)

Following lines (line 3 until 5) make zero sense to me:

> Since there is a valid use-case for class-private members (namely to
>   avoid name clashes of names with names defined by subclasses), there
>   is limited support for such a mechanism, called name mangling. Any
>   identifier of the form __spam (at least two leading underscores, at
>   most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with
>   _classname__spam, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped. This mangling is done without regard
>   to the syntactic position of the identifier, as long as it occurs
>   within the definition of a class.

If classname is the current class why does it say **with leading underscores stripped**? In the text everybody can see that the element `_classname__spam` **has** an underscore in front of it.

**EDIT**

Somehow there should be class names with leading underscores like __Welcome but in the learning materials i have always fould examples like:

```
class NamingNow:
    pass
```

...without underscores. However when i use the `dir` function i get something like

```
>>> dir(Mapping)
['_Mapping__update', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'update']
```

Does this rule pertain to this `__class__` thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's saying that if the class name itself contains leading underscores, they will be stripped, but another underscore will always be prepended. So a class named `_MyClass` would have attributes mangled to `_MyClass_spam`, not `__MyClass_spam`.

Comment: Why should a class name contain leading underscores? I always did class Penguin: for example i didnt put leading underscores in front of it and 99% of class definitions are usig names without leading underscores.

Comment: So what? This is a reference, it needs to definitively describe what happens in all circumstances.

Comment: So if i choose a name of a class like class _______Pirate: and this class has a private variable in it then the accesing of this private variable will be done so: the leading underscores will be taken out and one underscore will be prepended before the name Pirate because Python does so by format? Then Python will mangle the __spam behind. I think i am getting the gist

Comment: I think i got it Daniel. If i understood it wrong although please notify me.